# SharedPreferences and database: in native code or in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm currently migrating a native Android music app to Flutter. This app relies on:

- SharedPreferences
- a SQLite database, with 7 tables for the moment (I'm using Room on the native app)
- a `Service` where the player is

I try to migrate as much code as possible from native code to Flutter, since the app will also be available on iOS.

That said, the `Service` part (and its iOS equivalent) will be written using native code, since there is no equivalent in Flutter, as far as I know. Also, the audio player is already written (I won't use another one) since it's for a very specific use (it's written in C++ using OpenSL ES)

That apps makes a heavy use of the SharedPreferences and the database, inside ***and*** outside the `Service`.

So my question is: since a part of the app will still be written in native code, that will need to manipulate data in the SharedPreferences and in the database, what is the best approach: should I create and manipulate the SharedPreferences and the database using native code (Android and iOS), or using Flutter?

- if I do it using native code, I won't be able to take advantage of streams (correct me if I'm wrong)
- if I do it using Flutter, I'll have to call Dart code from my native code to request the database for example, and I'm not sure it's good practice...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need any native code at all.

You can use dart/flutter packages.

To use **shared Preference** you can add the package to your app and it will work out off the box for both android and IOS without any other configuration

link :

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

For the **DB** section there are wide number of choices
if you want a **SQL DB** you can use **sqflite** (not as smart as **ROOM** but it will do the job).

Link :

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

If you want to switch to Nosql DB i'll recommend Hive :
take a look here :

https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Finally to the service it depends on your need and your app complexity but for a music app i think the audiopLayers Package will do it :
take look here :

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

**Note that:**
Some packages may need some configuration to work something like edit androidManifest.xml or info.plist .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't answer my question: I need that `Service` because I have my own implementation of the audio player, which is written in C++ using OpenSL ES. So what is the best choice in that situation?